# Issues using path() in urls.py in django 2.0.5

Tags: python, django

I am following a tutorial which I'm trying to write in Django 2.0.5, but I got road block in the urls.py and I've been searching for a week, but still giving me Page not found (404) error message. 
Can someone give a clearer picture of path() as it seems to be not supporting regex.
Here is my code:

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
#from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Board

# Create your views here.
```

templates/topics.html

```
    {% load static %}<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>{{board.name}}</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 
       'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">>
    </head>
    <body>
     <div class="container">
        <ol class="breadcrumb my-4">
            <li class="breadcrumb-item">Boards</li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item active">{{board.name}}</li>
        </ol>
     </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

urls.py

```
   from django.contrib import admin
   from django.urls import path

   from boards import views


   urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),

    path('<int:pk>/', views.board_topics, name='board_topics'),

    path('admin/', admin.site.urls)

]
```

models.py

```
   from django.db import models
   from django.contrib.auth.models import User

   # Create your models here.

   class Board(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
      description = models.CharField(max_length=100)

     def __str__(self):
         return self.name


   class Topic(models.Model):
      subject = models.CharField(max_length=255)
      last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
      board = models.ForeignKey(Board, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      starter = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    # def __str__(self):
    #   return self.subject


  class Post(models.Model):
      message = models.TextField(max_length=4000)
      topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
      updated_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
      created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      #updated_by = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)

  #   def __str__(self):
        # return self.subject
```

and the error message in my browser

```
   Page not found (404)
   Request Method:  GET
   Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/board/1/
   Using the URLconf defined in myproject.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, 
   in this order:

   [name='home']
   <int:pk>/ [name='board_topics']
   admin/
   The current path, board/1/, didn't match any of these.

   You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django 
   settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 
   page.
```

Comment: Well you did not include the `board/` prefix, how did you include your `urls.py` of `board` in the **main** `urls.py` file?

Comment: hi Willem, the issue has been fixeed. here is the code `urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
 
    path('boards/<int:pk>/', views.board_topics, name='board_topics'),

    path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
    
]` thank you guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not defined a URL that matches `'/board/<pk>/'`. If you meant for the `board_topics` you currently have in your urls.py file to be that url then it should be `'board/<int:pk>/'` instead of just `'<int:pk>/'`.

Comment: Hi voodoo-burger, following your suggestion, the app works perfectly! here is the code `urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
 
    path('boards/<int:pk>/', views.board_topics, name='board_topics'),

    path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
    
]`